# Comparing huge data from 2 tables

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm using PHP and under localhost using Wamp. I have 2 tables from my database which has a huge data almost 13,000 plus each table. I want to check if NameFromA from TableA exist in NameFromB from TableB. I have this code working when I try to use small amount of data around 100 data.

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE  NameFromA = NameFromB)
```

My problem is when I try running it and comparing the 13,000 plus data nothing happens. It has no output.

Comment: May be it takes a lot of time to make such opeartion. From my point of view 13000 is very small amount of data. You can also redesing the query.

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov can you help me redesign my query. I have no idea on how to do it.

Comment: 13000 records is not "huge" by any means. Computers are very fast.

Comment: I post answer. Please check it because I primarily work with SQL Server and I am not sure for MySql syntax.

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins) may be useful to you (especially the Venn diagrams).

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov by the way I'm using wamp. localhost only.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  TableA.* 
FROM 
  TableA 
  INNER JOIN TableB ON (TableA.NameFromA = TableB.NameFromB)
```

If it is still slow, may be you have problem in the DB or the timeout time is too short.

You can also try to run this in MySql management too to see how long that query will take.

One more thing. The data that you retreive must be send to web server. If your table contains a lot of data for each row and there are a lot of rows this also will take time.

**EDIT:**

Ok @mar. You have to make a little troubleshooting to find where is the problem.

First: if your PC is powerfull enought. Because for normal PC and Server 13k records are nothing.

Second: are you sure that there are at least one name from table A which is presented in table B?

Third: try to run query in external SQL tool - not in php. If it retunrs correct set quickly, then the problem is in php.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `...JOIN TableB ON (A.a = B.b)`?

Comment: Unable to execute query.

Comment: 10x, @Sverri M. Olsen. I was in a hurry to explain answer so I made this very stupid mistake.

Comment: Sorry @mar. I fix it.

Comment: Answer of @Samir is also correct in general. But he must replace `*` with `a.*`.

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov by the way I'm using wamp. localhost only

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov yes my pc is powerful enough and I'm sure that there is at least one present in tablea from tableb..third it gives me timeout

Comment: Ok @mar. Run query in external editor to see how much it is running. Based on that you can try fix your problem. In general the amount of data is very small and the query is very simple. May be there are some specific indexes or configuration in your MySql DB which confise execution of the query (if it is in the query).

Answer (score 1):

Create index on column `NameFromA` in `TableA` and `NameFromB` in `TableB`.

Try below query:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM TableA AS a, TableB AS b
WHERE a.NameFromA = b.NameFromB
```

Comment: Replace `*` with `a.*`. The question requires to return data only from table `a`.

Comment: @Samir by the way I'm using wamp. localhost only